# Piping in on the command line simulating a file?

Tags: bash, command-line, pipe

I've seen the technique before, but don't know what it's called and forget the exact syntax. Let's say I need to pipe in a file to a program like: command < input-file. However, I want to directly pass these lines of the input file into the command without the intermediate input file. It looks something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
command < $(file-line1; file-line2; file-line3)
```

Can someone tell me what this is called and how to do it?

Comment: Given the wild variation in the answers that have just appeared, I think it's safe to say that your question is less than clear...

Comment: I didn't remember what it was called either. But my google query used words that were similar to the words in the title and body of this post. So this was a first hit for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is called `Process Substitution`

```
command < <(printf "%s\n" "file-line1" "file-line2" "file-line3")
```

With the above, `command` will think its being input a file with a name much like `/dev/fd/XX` where 'XX' is some number. As you mentioned, this is a temporary file (actually a file descriptor) but it will contain the 3 lines you passed in to the `printf` command.

Answer (score 2):

Herestring.

```
command <<< $'line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n'
```

Or heredoc.

```
command << EOF
line 1
line 2
line 3
EOF
```

Comment: Note that `herestrings` are `bashisms`, i.e. not POSIX-compliant;  `heredocs` are compliant and should work everywhere.  (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to a "here document". Like this

```
#!/bin/sh
cat <<EOF
This is
the 
lines.
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
cat myfile.txt | head -n3 | command
```